# Which law applies to the whole concentration range?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

If we are talking about two-component solutions can Henry's law be applied to the whole concentration range?
From what I understand Raoults and Daltons are used for smaller concentrations.

Comment: Henry's law  is for one liquid ans one gas, if the gases have independent partial pressure you can use it for  several gases. But I don't know what exactly you mean with two-component solutions, say Co2 and N2 in Water?

Comment: For ideal solutions, these laws apply over the fulll range of concentrations